# Memory Difference for Automatic Scale-Up vs. Larger Image with No Scale

Tags: android, image, bitmap, scale, resolution

I have a game with accidental occurrences of `OutOfMemoryException` when creating `Bitmap`.

For some resources I only use **one** image in the `drawable` folder (**MDPI**). That means there are no separate images for **HDPI**, **XHDPI** or **XXHDPI**.

Android up-scales them automatically when the resolution is higher.

*My questions is:* Is it more Memory efficient if I put inside the game initially upscaled images for each separate resolution - e.g. image for **HDPI**, image for **XHDPI** and relieve Android from the need to convert and rescale the `Bitmap` in memory, or is it better and more effiecent to use single image only for **MDPI** and Android to do the re-scale itself.

I think in that direction, because I don't know how much memory is needed internally for Android to re-scale the images when creating Bitmaps and if the Bitmap memory will be larger or smaller in each case. But it seems like a possible option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of efficiency and performance its almost always a better idea to provide scaled images instead of having Android to do it for you.

With that being said: In Android- Auto-scaling instead of pre-scaling can be more CPU expensive, but uses less memory. Unless you don't change the the scale of the image within the same session then it should not be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use your images in drawable-nodpi, so these are not scaled by the different densities.
When Android scales the image to dencity phone the phone are using memory, after your scales the image again , and you are using more memory,  and will throws OutOfMemoryException.

and you will put :

```
android:largeHeap="true"
```

For example:

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:theme="@style/TecnoblindsTHEME"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    tools:replace="android:icon,android:theme"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
 >
```

Check for displaying Bitmaps optimizing:

> http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html